# Help come up with a name for my StackOverflow app

Tags: discussion

With the SO API still in private beta, I wanted to give meta users a chance to have a say.

I created an app that lets you browse parts of SO with the eventual intention of the app being a replacement for accessing the site through a web browser. Here is a screenshot:

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/gui.jpg

I need a name for the application, so post your ideas as answers below.

**Update:** here is a Windows executable you can try

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/SOwhat_alpha.zip

**Update**: I decided to go with SOwhat. Thanks to everyone that entered and especially gnovices-exchange.

Comment: Where can I report errors/bugs? Seriously, I downloaded it, ran it, but it errored on startup with "An error occurred retrieving the user list" and when I clicked it away and searched on user with ID 1 it crashed with the error signature `AppName: gui demo.exe AppVer: 0.0.0.0 ModName: unknown ModVer: 0.0.0.0  Offset: 0000012e`.

Comment: @Balus: Thanks. Unfortunately, some changes to the API have caused the App to break. I am currently rewriting the app and the new version should have no problems and run faster.

Comment: @Balus: I fixed the bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- SOwhat
- SOcialite
- ReapWhatYeSO

Comment: SoWhat is my favorite so far.

Comment: I ended up picking SOwhat. Thanks!

Comment: This means that you can use the great Miles Davis track of the same name as your theme music, should you ever need one

Answer (score 4):

StackBrowser...

Comment: Like it cos it's not site specific

Comment: Oh right because Stack is also used in Super User and Server Fault :-P

Answer (score 3):

Focusing on the "alternative means of access" aspect:

- SideOverflow?
- SideEntrance?
- [Postern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postern)?

Comment: Why SideOverflow? Just curious...

Comment: @George a mix between "side entrance" and "stack overflow".

Answer (score 0):

- SO&SO (or SOandSO)
- SOCommando
- SOLoco

Answer (score 0):

StackOffice?
DeskStack?
StackTicker?
StackWatcher?

Comment: The last two sound like investment / day trading programs :)

Comment: @Tim, yeah, so does StackExchange, that's what got me thinking in that direction.

Answer (score -1):

BrowseSO

Answer (score -1):

iSOFU -- for Apple users

Comment: it's a windows app

Comment: BUT it was created with wxWidgets so a Mac version is easily possible.

Answer (score -1):

Since twitter has 'tweetdeck' , its conceivable that SE sites can have 'SEDeck'. I believe the API will eventually work on all SE sites?

Edited to reflect suggestions in comments. Its neat, because you could pronounce it 'sed - ek' or "see - deck'.

Comment: There are questions about boat programming. Sounds better than 'poopdeck'.

Comment: How about `SEdeck`? (slight change in spelling)